# Inserting into a linked list queue based on a compare function

Tags: c, linked-list, queue

I am implementing a single linked list version of a QueueADT. Upon Queue creation, if the client gives us a compare function, we are to use that on inserting new data into the queue. If the client does not provide a compare function, we use standard queue insertion and just insert to the back of the queue.

I am having trouble with the logic of using the compare function to insert. We only know what the compare function returns.

```
compare( void*a, void*b)
//compare returns < 0 if a < b
//compare returns = 0 if a == b
//compare returns > 0 if a > b
```

I have your standard queue and linked node structures:

```
typedef struct queueStruct {
    Node *front;
    Node *rear;
    int count;
    int (*compare)(const void*, const void*);
};

typedef struct Node {
    void* value;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;
```

And here is my attempt at the insert function. I don't think the logic is correct, and would appreciate some insight or maybe even pseudocode for this!

```
void que_insert(queueStruct queue, void *data){
    //if the queue is empty
    if (que_empty(queue)){
        Node *node;
        node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        node -> value = data;
        node -> next = NULL;
        queue->front  = node;
        queue->rear = node;
        queue->count++;
     }
     else{
        //if there is no comparison function, just use FIFO
        if (queue->compare == NULL){
            printf("Fifo\n");
            Node *node;
            node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
            node->value = data;
            node->next = NULL;
            queue->rear->next = node;
            queue->rear = node;
            queue->count++;

         }
         else{
            Node *temp;
            temp = queue->front;
            //if what we are adding is smaller than the head, then we found our new head
            if (queue->compare(data, temp->value) < 0){
                printf("Less Than 0\n");
                Node *node;
                node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                node->value = data;
                node->next = queue->front;
                queue->front = node;
                queue->count++;
                return;
             }
             while (temp->next != NULL){
                if (queue->compare(data, temp->value)> 0){
                    printf("Greater than 0\n");
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
                else if (queue->compare(data, temp->value) ==  0){
                    printf("Equals 0\n");
                    Node *node;
                    node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                    node->value = data;
                    node->next = temp->next;
                    temp->next = node;
                    queue->count++;
                    return;
                 }
             }
             //temp should be at the rear
             if (queue->compare(data, temp->value)> 0){
                printf("Adding to rear");
                Node *node;
                node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
                node->value = data;
                node->next = NULL;
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Testing:

Upon trying to insert the following data's into the queue:

```
42, 17, -12, 9982, 476, 2912, -22, 3291213, 7782
```

It seems that inserting these values works up until the last one, the program hangs at

```
inserting 7782
Greater than 0
Greater than 0
Greater than 0
Greater than 0
```

Comment: Hey, sorry, I just added what exactly im looking for here, thanks!

Comment: But you've already written some code. so whats wrong?

Comment: What drives your conclusion your logic isn't correct? That is doesn't work? What ***does*** it do, and have you any suspicion for **why**? One thing you can do to clean up some of the clutter is realize you're *always* going to add a node, so allocate it in *one* place at the beginning of the function, and then the rest of the function can be dedicated to finding where to wedge it in.

Comment: Unrelated: Your `Node` structure type-decl is missing the keyword `typedef`. All it does as-written is declare a variable called `Node`. And `queueStruct` is missing similar declaration type-defing if it is to be used in your presented code as-shown. As-written it is used as a pointer type, but type-defed as a structure type, so all the `->` usage won't even compile.

Comment: Hi Craig, the program hangs after adding the last value. I edited the original post to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First. You do not need all the added comparator invocations if your comparison requires a strict weak ordering (which it should). This essentially means the following

```
if (compare(a,b) < 0) 
    then a is less than b
else if !(compare(b,a) < 0) 
    then a and b are equal
else b is less than a
```

This is commonly used in standard libraries because, for one, it makes the comparison enumeration must easier to follow. It also only requires *one* logical operation be defined. "less"

As I said in general comment, consolidate where your new node is allocated. It appears your queue supports duplicates (it should), and thus no matter what you're always adding a new node, so just make it from the outset and then concentrate on finding where it goes.

Finally, a pointer-to-pointer-to-Node will make your insertion considerably more concise (in fact, I'm betting you'll find it remarkably short):

```
void que_insert(queueStruct* queue, void *data)
{
    // going to need this sooner or later
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    node->value = data;
    node->next = NULL;

    //if the queue is empty
    if (queue->count == 0)
    {
        queue->front = queue->rear = node;
        queue->count = 1;
    }

    // else not empty, but no comparator
    else if (queue->compare == NULL)
    {
        //if there is no comparison function, just use FIFO
        queue->rear->next = node;
        queue->rear = node;
        queue->count++;
    }

    // else not empty and we have a comparator
    else
    {   // walk over chain of node pointers until we  find a pointer 
        //  that references a node equal or greater than ours, or EOQ
        Node **pp = &queue->front;
        while (*pp && queue->compare((*pp)->value, data) < 0)
            pp = &(*pp)->next;

        // no more nodes means new rear. otherwise link mid-stream
        if (!*pp)
            queue->rear = node;
        else
            node->next = *pp;

        // either way, this is always done.
        *pp = node;
        queue->count++;
    }
}
```

**How It Works**

We use a pointer-to-pointer-to-Node to hold the address of each pointer we're examining, starting with the head pointer. This has several advantages. We don't need to keep track of a pointer to node just to have access to its "next", since we already have it *by address*. We get automatic front-insertion because we start with the head-pointer *address*, The only consideration that must be made is the *rear* update, which still must be done manually, but it is trivial.

Pointer-to-pointer traversal may seem a little daunting a first, but it has some wonderful characteristics. there is no pointer-to-node enumerator. You're actually using the pointers *in the list* as your enumeration variables. Not just their "values", but the actual pointers *and* their values. All you're doing is changing which one you're using by updating an address in a pointer-to-pointer to reflect which physical pointer *in the list* (not just *to* the list) that you're dealing with. When it comes time to change something, you don't need a pointer to the node who's "next" pointer you need to change; you already have *the address* of the pointer you're going to modify, and therefore can do so immediately.

I've not tested the code attached, but it should work. Just make sure your initial `queueStruct` is setup for zero count with NULL on both rear and front pointers. That is (obviously) important.

Finally, I *strongly* advise stepping through this with a debugger. There is no substitute for "seeing" the actual pointer addresses and values flying through the code. A pencil and a piece of paper with boxes, arrows to boxes, and arrows to arrows to boxes also helps considerably in understanding the algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much, the code works! I am going to take your advice and grab a pencil and paper to help me understand what exactly is going on here. One question, why do we not have to link the old rear's next to the new rear when we find no more nodes?

Comment: @NesBa The answer to your question is in the dissection of how a pointer-to-pointer can be used. the last node in the linked list has a `next` pointer. It is *that* pointer who's *address* `pp` holds when we exhaust the list and reach the end. That pointer will be where we hang the new rear. Remember. `pp` doesn't point to a node; it points to a pointer. If the pointer it points-to is NULL, it means we're at list-end, so hang the new node on that pointer and set the rear pointer to the same node. Trust me, debug it and walk it out on paper. It will make sense.

Comment: @NesBa and honestly I thought you would find the auto-magic update to the head-pointer more intriguing, in the event a node should be placed at the *beginning* of the list. Thats the one that normally makes people scratch their heads. I don't think I can describe how it works much better, so definitely pencil it out.